# which is better to execute Database query on MainActivity or SubActivity

Tags: android

i currently following [tutorial making notepad](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html), this tutorial using 2 activity main activity and edit activity, edit activity is using to fill data for database , but the query is executed in main activity 
so the data must sent back `OnActivityResult` from edit activity to main activity . 
     
the main question is i want to know why we must pass data to main activity instead of execute insert or update query on edit Activity, is this the best way?,

Can anyone explain why?
Thanks

Comment: I would say the best place to be running queries isn't in any activity but in a helper class that will run the query and then return the results to the activity.

Comment: Sorry , what I mean by execute query is calling helper to execute the query to insert data from activity that call the helper ...

Answer (score 0):

There you have the 2 activities, one (Main) is meant ust to display the notes, the other (Edit) will let the user to create the note. When the user confirms the creation of the new note in the EditActivity, it will finish and in the MainActivity's "onActivityResult" the notes will be loaded and displayed in the list. So if you want to separate the creation from the visualization of the (I highly suggest you to do this), you want this approach.

Comment: i think main activity function are both creation and visualization , 
creation because query execution to create, insert , update database is in main Activity